# How do I call a function on each <li> when they near the top of the viewport?

Tags: jquery, offset, viewport, scrolltop

**Please help.  I'm losing sleep over this one! :)**

I have a list of short posts; call them quotes if you will.  I have a fixed position header that is 200px high with a transparent background.  I need the header visible for each and every post that the user scrolls through (hence the fixed positioning), and I'd like the read posts to disappear (or lower substantially in opacity) when they are scrolled up and behind the header; an inverse of "lazyload"  with a 200px pad, if you will.  Of course if the user scrolls the opposite direction to have the post back in the viewport (and below the header), I need it to reappear.

I'm fairly new with jQuery so please bear with me.  I've searched extensively for help and hints but no fix yet.  Your help is sincerely appreciated!

**Mockup:**

[Test Page](http://assets.bradcerasani.me/mockup/)

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var headerheight = $('#header').height();
  var scrollposition = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var offset = .offset();

        $('li').each(function() {

            if(scrollposition <= $(this)offset.top-headerheight){

            // 
            $(this).fadeOut(400);
            // 

            } else {

            //
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
            //

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Used this plugin: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var headerheight = $('#header').height();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollposition = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('li').each(function() {
            var obj = $('.test');

            if(scrollposition >= headerheight){

                if(obj.css('display') == 'none') {
                    $('.test').fadeIn(400);
                }

            } else {

                if(obj.css('display') == 'block') {
                    $('.test').fadeOut(400);
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

There was quite a bit flaws in it and errors. But my modification should do the trick. As you we're capturing the scroll position only once it would never update. Which would lead to if statements always going to wrong way :) This will only fade the .test class in or out if it's not already faded in or out.

Give it a try and let me know if it worked :)

Remember that this will fade the .test class in/out if the scroll position is higher or equal to the height of #header -

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If I employ your solution, it successfully fades in/out ".test" relative to the scroll position of the first <li>, but what I need it to do is independently act upon each <li> as they approach this fade threshold.  If I add 'test' as a class to the other list items, then they all hide when the first <li> reaches the headerheight threshold.  Am I missing something?  Thanks again!

Comment: So what you need is as the user scroll down the page and one of the items comes to the end of the page(top) it shall fade it out?

Comment: Precisely.  I'm thinking .fadeTo() instead of .fadeOut() as to not fully remove each <li> from the page (which would affect height).

Comment: Well i will sketch one up for you tomorrow once i got time. The thing you could do here is to use animate and then opacity to not effect the height of the list. But i will sketch it tomorrow :) Keep an eye for it in this answer - The edited version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll watch for it! :)

Comment: I'm sooo for answering your reply. I completely forgot about stackoverflow for a little while. I see you found an answer for your question. That's good to hear :)